# Is there a way to bypass va_copy when using vsnprintf?

Tags: c

I'm introducing a 3rd party protocol stack to on an old embeded platform where all va_* stuff are implemented except va_copy. The problem I face is, in the 3rd party stack, vsnprintf() is used:

```
int fun(char **buf, size_t buf_size, const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
  va_list ap_copy;
  int len;
  /* first call*/
  va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
  len = vsnprintf(*buf, buf_size, fmt, ap_copy);
  va_end(ap_copy);
  if(len >= buf_size)
  {
      /* 2nd call*/
      va_copy(ap_copy, ap);
      len = vsnprintf(*buf, len + 1, fmt, ap_copy);
      va_end(ap_copy);
  }  
}
```

Luckily the 3rd party stack provedes its own vsnprintf function(call it new_vsnprintf), but without va_copy, only the first call works, i.e, when the len is small than buf_size. Below is the way I call it:

```
#define vsnprintf new_vsnprintf
int fun(char **buf, size_t buf_size, const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
  //va_list ap_copy;
  int len;
  /* first call*/
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  len = vsnprintf(*buf, buf_size, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  if(len >= buf_size)
  {
      /* 2nd call*/
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      len = vsnprintf(*buf, len + 1, fmt, ap);  //new_vsnprintf()
      va_end(ap);
  }  
}
```

Problem occurs in the 2nd call of new_vsnprintf(), when trying to get the actual value of placeholders by `va_arg()`. I assume the inner pointer of (va_list) ap points to wrong memory address.
Then how to correct it?

Comment: With C++, you might use variadic template to resolve your issue. But you have both tag C and C++.

Comment: sry, it is C. Removed C++ alrady @Jarod42

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling `va_start()` as the code that calls `fun` should have done that already - that's why you pass in `ap`

Comment: @ChrisTurner but before the 1st call of `fun`, `va_start()` is called, and it works ok.

Comment: Maybe you could add a working `va_copy` (obviously the details of that cannot be suggested by us based on the information you haven't posted)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling either `va_start` or `va_end` in your function `fun`. They should only be called in functions that have `...` in the argument list to indicate that there are a variable number of arguments. My version of gcc (4.8.4) even throws up an error if I try and compile your code as it currently exists.

```
test.c: In function ‘fun’:
test.c:14:3: error: ‘va_start’ used in function with fixed args
   va_start(ap, fmt);
```

It seems likely that calling them in functions with fixed args is causing undefined behaviour and it's luck that the first call to `vsnprintf` is actually working.

Since you're not calling `va_arg` inside `fun` the value of `ap` shouldn't be changing and you should be able to call `vsnprintf` as many times as you require.

Comment: No, `va_arg` is called in `new_vsnprintf()`. Since I cannot get a duplicate of ap by `va_copy`, I want to reset the `ap` (which has been changed by `va_arg` in the 1st call) for next call by `va_end`.

Comment: If it's being changed (which I find surprising/odd since you're passing it into `new_vsnprinf` by value) the only place you can reset it with `va_start`, is in the function with `...` as that's the only function that has the necessary information to (re)build the `va_list`

Comment: Uh...I get it. Maybe I should think over whether I can make the 2nd call a seprate function, then it's possible to reset ap.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may work if your platform has a simple varargs handling, like most platform do. If your platform do not permit va_list object to be trivially copied this cannot work. On most platforms va_copy is a simple macro that does some thing like:

```
#define va_copy(dest, src) dest = src
```

... this is the case for x86, ppc and many other targets. Anyway here is the code, I hope it works, I've no way to test or confirm it works without knowing the platform you are using it on!

```
int fun(char **buf, size_t buf_size, const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
  va_list ap_copy = ap;
  int len;
  /* first call*/
  va_start(ap_copy, fmt);
  len = vsnprintf(*buf, buf_size, fmt, ap_copy);
  va_end(ap_copy);
  if(len >= buf_size)
  {
      /* 2nd call*/
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      len = vsnprintf(*buf, len + 1, fmt, ap);  //new_vsnprintf()
      va_end(ap);
  }  
}
```

Comment: no, I tried this at the very beginning. `ap_copy = ap` even does not compile. The compiler is an very old version of Diab(WindRiver).